# MySQL how to find and compare min and max values in the same row

Tags: mysql, compare, row, max, min

I have searched but have been unable to find a solution that can be successfully adapted to my query.

I have built a database that holds advertising banners and my script rotates and displays each each banner in succession, however I am trying to add in a query that will search in the table and display the banner with the highest CTR (click through ratio) based on its MIN impressions (amount of times the banner has been shown) and MAX clicks (the number of times the banner has been clicked)

I have tried many different combinations of the search query some of them the syntax is wrong and others appear to have the correct syntax but fail to produce the expected results, this is the last query I have tried :

```
$query = "SELECT banner_id,banner_url,banner_alt,banner_size FROM banner_ads WHERE $banner_niche$banner_size banner_enable=1 AND banner_impressions=(SELECT MIN(banner_impressions) FROM banner_ads WHERE banner_clicks=(SELECT MAX(banner_clicks) FROM banner_ads));";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "\nQuery: $query");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
$banner_id = $row[0];
$banner_url = $row[1];
$banner_alt = $row[2];
list($banner_width, $banner_height) = split("x", $row[3]);
```

An example of the the field contents are :

```
banner_id / banners row ID number : 1
banner_url / URL to the banner image : http://somesite.com/banner.jpg
banner_alt / banner alt text : Visit SomeSite.com
banner_size / size of the banner : 468x60
banner_niche / the category of the banner : books
banner_enable / is the banner set to display or not : 1
banner_impressions / number of times banner has been shown : 1000
banner_clicks / number if time banner has been clicked : 50
```

So simply I need query to search the table for a banner that has the least impressions with the most clicks.

```
----------------------------------------------
banner_id | banner_impressions | banner_clicks
----------------------------------------------
1         | 1000               | 50
2         | 100                | 80
3         | 2000               | 90
----------------------------------------------
```

So in the above example banner_id 2 would match the criteria. (I skipped the other fields in the example because they are not relevant)

Thanks in advance guys, I hope I have explained well enough what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: What if something has 50 impressions and 100 clicks. and another has 55 impressions and 150 clicks. Which would you choose?

Comment: Without it getting even more complex than it already is then it would be 50/100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the highest ratio of clicks to banner ads, this query would work

```
  select banner_id, banner_impressions, banner_clicks, rank() over 
    (order by click_toimpression DESC)
    as ranks FROM
        (
 select banner_id, banner_impressions, banner_clicks, 
    (banner_clicks /  banner  impressions) 
    as Click_ToImpression FROM banner_ads
    );
```

--for the highest rank

```
   Select * FROM
    (
  select banner_id, banner_impressions, banner_clicks, rank() over 
    (order by click_toimpression DESC)
    as ranks FROM
        (
 select banner_id, banner_impressions, banner_clicks, 
    (banner_clicks /  banner  impressions) 
    as Click_ToImpression FROM banner_ads
    )) WHERE ranks = 1
```

;

```
 MySQL

  select banner_id, banner_impressions, banner_clicks, 
    (banner_clicks /  banner  impressions) 
    as Click_ToImpression FROM banner_ads) ORDER BY Click_toImpression DESC 
    LIMIT 1;
```

this would rank your ratios. To get the highest, just select the max from that, if you just want the one row.

This ranks them by a click to banner ad ratio, instead of arbitrarily getting the min and max and trying to gather information from that. I *think* this is along the lines of what you're looking for, and how I would approach this problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this... I tried the above but it threw up a syntax error, I then noticed an underscore was missing from banner impressions so I added it in that solved the syntax error, but alas did not produce any results... Unless I am trying to "select the the max from that* using the wrong technique.

Comment: Hmm, it should work. Check my edited solution for selecting the highest ratio row

Comment: I just tried the highest rank version and still getting the syntax error, again I tried reformatting it a bit but still a syntax error, I even made a small test file that just connects to the DB and runs that query alone... One plus is you do know exactly what I am trying to achieve though... thanks

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you're on mySQL. Use the bottom query I just added instead.

Comment: AWESOME ! after adding the missing ( and quite a few adjustments to my original script in order to include this aspect it is working great ! Thank you for taking the time to help me here Scotch greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: No problem, sorry about my first suggestion -- for some reason I thought you were using oracle:p